# Error: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [component-scan] after upgrading to Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, xsd, spring-ws

After I have upgraded spring to 3.2.3.RELEASE, I am getting the following error on Tomcat startup in Eclipse:

```
ug 12, 2013 1:59:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [component-scan].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.findParserForElement(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:63)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultXmlBeanDefinitionParser.parseCustomElement(DefaultXmlBeanDefinitionParser.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultXmlBeanDefinitionParser.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultXmlBeanDefinitionParser.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultXmlBeanDefinitionParser.registerBeanDefinitions
```

Here's my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="merchant" />    
     <context:component-scan
        base-package="merchant.domain" />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="merchant.controller" />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="merchant.repo" />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="merchant.service" />

    <!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
    <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />

    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

I searched online a lot for a solution, but couldn't find any relevant ones. 
Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This error is very likely because the `spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar` is somehow not being found in the classpath after your upgrade. Please do check your dependency and make sure this jar is in the list of dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked it. The jar is found correctly in the classpath. I was having another issue due to old version of Spring and that got resolved. Hence, it must be working. But still I am getting the above error.

Comment: Strange..cannot think of anything else, is there any way that some other spring-context jar is being detected? Also, see if you can find this type, `org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler`, this is the class that handles the `context` namespace.

Comment: I included spring-2.5.6.jar, which contains the above class. Still the same error.

Comment: Can it be anything to do with the spring version I mentioned in xsi:schemaLocation inside applicationContext.xml?

Comment: spring-2.5.6 is an old version..any reason to mix spring-context-3.2.3 with spring-2.5.6, I would just go ahead and remove the older version. That should fix things.